# method show laravel livewire

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel, livewire

Hola alguien tiene alguna idea de utilizar el metodo show en un componente de livewire, es para  ver mas detalles de un registro ya que son muchos campos y se me ocurre presentarlos de esta manera,
Devolucion:
Factura:
Cliente:
etc
En formato horizontal y no en formato vertical como si fuera una tabla
e Estado investigado como hacerlo con mount pero aun no doy
mi componente

```
   public function render() {
       return view('livewire.motivodevolucion');
   }
   public $message;
   public function mount() {

       $this->message= DB::table('facturas')->select('motivo_devolucion','devm')->where('id')->get();
   }
```

y mi vista del componente

```
<div>

   <div class="col-md-6">
       <div>
           <label  form="pedido" class="text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold">Motivo:
               {{ $message }}</label><br>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: puedes cargar los modelos en la vista, con el método render.

Answer (score 0):

Para cargar data o modelos en la vista puedes usar el método render() con eloquent.

```
public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.motivodevolucion',
    ['$messages' => Facturas::where('id',$id)->get(['motivo_devolucion','devm'])
       
        ]
    );
}
```